# symfony 2.1 - dev environment faster than prod

Tags: performance, symfony, environment

I'm using Symfony 2.1 and my dev environment is 6 time faster than my prod...
Indeed I made this method to perform some test

```
public static function perfAction(){
            return new Response("ok");
}
```

This is displayed in 110ms in dev environment and 900ms in the prod
Can you help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Does this happen on fresh copy of symfony-standard-edition? You can download 2.1 version of symfony standard here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/tree/2.1

Comment: Symfony 2.1 is out of maintenance. Use Symfony 2.4!